# Why does java ParNew young generation collection degrade to single CPU with CMS?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've been unable to find an explanation of which phase of young collection is actually serialized to a single CPU.   My speculation is that is when doing the first fit (best fit?) search in the old generation.

From what I've been able to glean, the horrible performance we see deals with the eden size being to small, and we end up unnecessarily copying lots of data into the old generation.

We hit periods were the process basically stops in young GC, and CPU utilization  drops to about 1 CPU for sometimes a minute or to.  We are not seeing evidence that we actually fail to allocate in the old generation due to fragmentation.

We're using -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC with 16GB or 31GB heaps on 32 CPU machines.   Both on Java 7 and Java 8 (u66) .  Will upgrading help this?

Comment: Is the CPU time spent in user or kernel space? You should provide some GC logs. If java 8 logs are not detailed enough you could try a java9 prerelease and log with `-Xlog:gc*=trace,tlab*=off:file=gc.log` which logs almost everything GC-related. As far as logs are concerned ParNew does not seem to have distinct phases like G1.

Comment: for java 8 log with `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintReferenceGC`. see [this blog post](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/09/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) for a cheatsheet

Comment: I will see if PrintReferenceGC yields more info.  The standard GC logging in ElasticSearch was not including that.     The logs show many young collections > 1s, and some concurrent mode failures.   Nothing very interesting.   I was really looking for an detailed description of the GC phases.  All of the documentation I've found so far is pretty high level.

Comment: I don't recall any of the young gen GCs breaking down the young collection into phases in the logs. Except G1 that is. ParNew, DefNew and PScavange do mostly the same things conceptually. http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem with GC, and understand what was happening, but not exactly which part of ParNew young GC was actually serialized to a single CPU.

It turns out that if you are using CMS, then the documented default value of NewRatio, 2, is not used, even on a new Java 8. Simply specifying -XX:NewRatio=2 on the command line got us completely out of GC hell on our 31GB heap ElasticSearch instances. The "this is not a bug, its a feature"  explanation is here:  http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8153578

The young size we had been getting was 1.4GB, rather than the ~10GB we expected from the default NewRatio.   Therefore at high thread counts, the young data was treated as tenured, even though we had plenty of memory.

Related to this, we have noticed a phenomenon with thread pools, such as ElasticSearch has.  The eden size was large enough for the typical 8-12 threads that would typically run, but if the load increased, we'd descend into GC hell.  So if you have a server with thread pools, the eden sizing needs to be based on cases where all the threads are in use.